# Cakephp how to create dropdown list from table

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp and am trying to create a really simple api where the user can 'reserve' a vehicle through an api.

I have three Models, Views and Controllers, which are Vehicles, Customers and Reservations. I have implemented most of it but i am just stuck on how i can add a reservation by allowing the user to pick from a dropdown list.

Basically i want two dropdown lists that allow me to select the customer id/name and vehicle id/name. and put them into the reservations table.

This is my reservations controller add function

```
function add() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Reservation->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The Reservation was successfully added!');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The Reservation was not added.');
            }
        }
        $customers = $this->Customers->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('customers'));
        $this->set('title_for_layout','Add Reservation');
    }
```

At the bottom i have used some code from a different website that should create a list of customers, but i get an error. Also because the customers content is in a different model, im guessing this is the wrong way to go about it.

So how can i add a dropdown list of customers to my reservations page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model-names should be *singular*, not *plural*, so try this

```
$customers = $this->Customer->find('list');
```

However, you may have forgotten to load the 'Customer' model in your controller. Ff the `Reservation` model has a relation with `Customer` (e.g. Reservation belongsTo Customer), it's better to access it via the Model-tree;

```
$customers = $this->Reservation->Customer->find('list');
$this->set(compact('customers'));
```

To get rid of the intermediate variable, use this:

```
$this->set('customers', $this->Reservation->Customer->find('list'));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. It is now giving me this error:- 'Call to a member function find() on a non-object'

Comment: @user667430 That would mean your `Reserveration belongsTo Customer` association has not been set. If you associate them, the find should work.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I managed to fix the relationships out. It works.

Answer (score -1):

**Make list array in controller**.

```
$role=$this->Modelname->find('list',array('fields'=>'id,name'));
```

**Make drop  down list in `ctp` file like this.**

```
echo $this->Form->input('role', array('options' => $roles, 'default' => '--Select--'));
```